# Updated from PHP74 to PHP8 -> PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT not working

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I updated the PHP-Version on my Server (Windows Server 2017, IIS) from PHP74 to PHP8. Since then the PDO option ATTR_TIMEOUT has stopped working: `SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An unsupported attribute was designated on the PDO object.`

Not working:
`$this->db = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->pwd, array(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 60));`

Working: `$this->db = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->pwd);`

Unfortunately I couldn't find any indication why this option no longer works and what the alternative is.

Comment: what database engine are you trying to connect to?

Comment: We use an Oracle Database. I am not sure which version is running on the database server and whether I then have to select the appropriate extension in php.ini? In PHP74 this was extension = pdo_oci; extension = oci8_12c;. In PHP8 is use extension = pdo_oci; extension = oci8_19;

Comment: The question is: what were you expecting it to do, and did it do that in the old version?  There isn't any code in PDO_OCI to do anything with this attribute.   I'd have to look more (when I'm back from vacation) to give a deeper answer.